# C++: Declaring non-global variables in header?

Tags: c++, header

In the code below, y is used in func().  While the code compiles, in terms of convention and/or optimization, does y need to be declared in the header file?  If so, is there anyway I can prevent y from appearing in every file that includes the header?

```
   //func.h
    #ifndef FUNC_H
    #define FUNC_H

    int func(const int x);

    #endif // FUNC_H
    //


    //func.cpp
    const int y = 5;

    int func(const int x)
    {
      return x + y;
    }
    //
```

Comment: if y is used only in the func, why not declare inside the func

Comment: My understanding is that if I call func() multiple times, y will have to be initialized multiple times.  To avoid this, I want to give it higher scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if `y` is only used in func.cpp then there is no need (in terms of convention or performance) to declare it in the header file. What you have looks fine to me.

A constant implicitly has internal linkage so it is only accessible inside func.cpp.

You could consider making it `constexpr`.

If `y` is only used in `func()` you could consider declaring it inside `func()`. I
think to assume a global variable will perform better is premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

one option

In the header file have the declaration

```
extern const int y;
```

In one of the source files define the variable

```
const int y =5;
```

Comment: Yes but then y appears in every source file that includes the header file.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: @AgrimPathak, as it is a declaration alone. you will have only one address for y .